# App crashes due to SetOnClickListener NullPointerException (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

The app is basically (as of yet) a login/sign up page
I'm having trouble switching activities... the app crashes when I add the setOnClickListener.

```
class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        configureBtnSignUp();
        configureBtnResetPassword();
    }


    private void configureBtnSignUp(){
        Button btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void configureBtnResetPassword(){
        Button btnResetPassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);
        btnResetPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PwRecoverActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }


}
```

This is the error code

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                      at kardacorporation.bandme.LoginActivity.configureBtnSignUp(LoginActivity.java:24)
                      at kardacorporation.bandme.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:18)
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: I suggest you read the answers to the two questions linked above. They both describe how to figure out what causes the problem that you see here.

Answer (score 2):

*The reason is that you are trying to set a listener to a button that don't have reference in your layout.*

The problem is related with btn_reset_password

Be sure that in your layout have a button with id **btn_reset_password**

In your activity_login:

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btn_reset_password"
     ...
 </Button>
```

Nice coding!

Answer (score 1):

According to Logcat, Your problem is

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

It happened in

> kardacorporation.bandme.LoginActivity. **configureBtnSignUp**(LoginActivity.java:24)`

So we should check `configureBtnSignUp` method first .

Make sure you have **btn_signup** id in your xml code .

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_signup" 
    ...                         />
```

And you call `configureBtnSignUp` method before calling `configureBtnResetPassword` method .

So you should check `configureBtnResetPassword` method .

And make sure you have **btn_reset_password**  id in your xml code .

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_reset_password" 
    ...                         />
```